# sql job executing ssrs report shows success even if the report is stuck in deadlock

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, sql-server-agent

I have created an email subscription for SSRS report.

When I execute the report by the Subscription, it shows the job successfully completed. But, the email is not received as the report is still executing, because one of the tables is in lock. Once the lock is released I receive the email of report.

Shouldn't the job wait for the lock to be released and the subscription mail to be sent before marking it as complete?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it's an asynchronous process. The job is recorded as started and it should get updated by the result of the subscription. Try going back and checking when a job has failed in the creation of the report or sending of the email. The status messages from the subscriptions are limited and usually just show the last message.